# Print file data content column wise

Tags: bash, ubuntu, awk

I have a tab separated file `file.txt` whose contents are as follows :

```
word11 word12 word13 word14
word21 word22 word23 word24
word31 word32 word33 word34
word41 word42 word43 word44
```

I want to copy each column in a different file. For example:
First file will have contain :

```
word11
word21
word31
word41
```

Second file will contain:

```
word12
word22
word32
word42
```

I wrote the script for the same (There are 12 columns):

```
for i in {1..12}
do
        awk -F "\t" '{print $i}' file.txt > /tmp/output-$i.txt
done
```

But all output files contain all the data:

```
word11 word12 word13 word14
word21 word22 word23 word24
word31 word32 word33 word34
word41 word42 word43 word44
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: you could just use cut

Comment: Awk doesn't know about the shell variable `$i` so it evaluates to empty, hence your print statement is simply `print`, which prints the whole line. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to use shell variables in `Awk` which would *never* work. But what you are trying to do can be done totally in `Awk` itself. The for loop upto `NF` will parse all your columns, you don't need to hard-code it anymore.

```
awk -v FS="\t" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i > ("/tmp/output-"i);}'  file.txt
```

Comment: Never say never: `$ for i in {1..4} ; do awk "{print \$$i}" file.txt > output-$i; done` ;)

Comment: @JamesBrown: Yup but double-quotes for `Awk` is something I never recommend ;)

Answer (score 3):

You could instead just use cut

```
for i in {1..12}
do
    cut -f$i file.txt > /tmp/output-$i.txt;
done
```